# How two select two column value as key value pair in mongoose using expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i have the schema is like below
Resource.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
objectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;
var lableShema = new Schema({
labelName: { type: String },
language: { type: String, },
resourceKey: { type: String, },
resourceValue: { type: String, }
}, {
    versionKey: false
});

var lableShema = mongoose.model('LabelKeyResource', lableShema);
module.exports = lableShema;
```

in db i have the data like this,

```
{
    "_id": "59b1270b4bb15e1358e47cbd",
    "labelName": "submit",
    "__v": 0,
    "resourceKey": "submit_btn",
    "resourceValue": "Submit",
    "language": "engilish"
}
```

i'm using the select function is

```
 lableResource.find({ language: req.params.ln}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }
 res.send(data);
```

but i want this format how to that...

```
{"submit_btn":"Submit","select_lbl":"Please Select"}
```

Comment: Did not got your question, how is current find working if universityId field is not there in schema/db ? Also submit_btn and select_lbl keys are also not there.

Comment: Sorry i was typed wrongly, now i change the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the data after getting the data from Mongo.
This is how you can do it:

```
var obj = {
   [data.resourceKey]: data.resourceValue,
   select_label: "Please Select"
};
```

This will give you the object: `{"submit_btn":"Submit","select_lbl":"Please Select"}`